# porting python ctypes from linux to windows, testing

Tags: python, linux, windows, ctypes, porting

I'm currently trying to contribute to an open source python package (`ObsPy`) with a python module that uses c-code at its core (using `ctypes`). The code I'm adding have been developed, tested, used on `linux` for several years now. The `ObsPy` project is hosted on github with with several build and test actions activated. I've gotten as far as to get my contribution to build properly but all the tests fail on windows (no reported issues for the linux or mac builds and tests). The code piece I'm contributing with is an update of a reader/writer for a data format (GCF) and I suspect that the issue lies in my attempt to use pre-compiler macros to swap between the use of file i/o functions on linux/windows, basically:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN64) || defined(_WIN64)
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <inttypes.h>
   #include <io.h>
   #include <BaseTsd.h>
   typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t;   
   #ifndef O_RDONLY
      #define O_RDONLY _O_RDONLY
   #endif 
    
   #ifndef O_WRONLY
      #define O_WRONLY _O_WRONLY
   #endif  
    
   #ifndef O_CREAT
      #define O_CREAT _O_CREAT
   #endif  
    
   #ifndef O_TRUNC
      #define O_TRUNC _O_TRUNC
   #endif 
    
   #ifndef open
      #define open(path, flags, mode) _open(path, flags, mode)
   #endif
    
   #ifndef close
      #define close(fd) _close(fd)
   #endif
    
   #ifndef write
      #define write(fd, buffer, count) _write(fd, buffer, count)
   #endif
    
   #ifndef read
      #define read(fd, buffer, count) _write(fd, buffer, count)
   #endif
    
   #define FPERM _S_IWRITE
#else
   #include <unistd.h>
   #define FPERM  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
#endif
```

So I'm seeking advice on either how to improve this (if there are some obvious flaws with this approach) or if there is some appropriate (free) tools around that I can use locally on my `linux` machine to build in a `windows` environment and run the tests in order to pinpoint and fix the problem.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but if you'd include a link to your efforts, someone might take an actual look and propose improvements. ;)

Comment: You'll have to check how the *Win* build works for *ObsPy* (tollchain, etc) If it's *VStudio* based all macros you defined (or almost all of them) already exist, so there's no need for the above snippet. The error lies somewhere else.  As a note: when using values like 2147483647, you could prefer their *hex* form (0x7fffffff), as the former doesn't say anything to many people. Also `#if defined(_WIN32)` is enough.

Comment: @CristiFati, not entirely clear from the action logs as the build commands are not present. But under the conda environment mingw64 is listed to presumably this is used. In any case the defined macros seems necessary else build will fail.

Comment: @Ulrich: https://github.com/obspy/obspy/pull/3055

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar code in other projects, including the MSVC C library. The challenge this code faces is that it tries to mimick the POSIX API using the WinAPI, only using a handful of preprocessor macros. However, those APIs are very different the more you go into details.

My advise for you would be to provide a separate WinAPI implementation for low-level stuff instead of trying to shoe-horn the code into compiling on both systems. Instead, consider creating a common interface on a higher abstraction level.

Concerning the question about testing on Linux, you might be able to use a cross-compiler, e.g. mingw. That would at least cover the compilation part of it.

Comment: The compilation part finishes with no reported errors when using the macros shown above. So that I need some dev. environment to run tests in in order to figure out what the compiled library really does. Even if I were to separate the low-level stuff in two separate pieces of code I still would need some way to test it. Naively I tried to add some `printf` statements in the c-code and  let the github actions try it out but it seems that it just digests output to `stdout` from the c-code (output to `stdout` from the python part does make it into the action logs but that's of no help).